Tengo este problema cuando ejecuto npm start: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'worker_threads',
Problema con Single Page Application en Node.js: Error con worker_threads y polyfills en webpack
Estoy creando una single page application básica con Node.js y tengo problemas cuando ejecuto npm start. Aquí están los errores que recibo:
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'worker_threads'

Advertencia
BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js 
core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and 
configure a polyfill for it.

Agradecería mucho si alguien me pudiera ayudar a resolver estos errores. Aquí está un resumen de mi configuración actual:
Node.js versión: 22.2.0
webpack versión: 5.91.0
Sistema operativo: Windows 10

Pasos que he seguido:
Instalé todas las dependencias con npm install.
Cambie de version de node js
Esta es mi configuracion de webpack
https://github.com/JuanAgudelo1015/SPA/blob/master/webpack.config.js.
De ante mano les agradeceria mucho si me colaboran con esto.

edita la pregunta y renueve etiquetas que no tiene nada que ver con e tema,  Ejemplo  server, php´

No puedes usar worker_threads en una SPA. Si bien estás usando node para ejecutar el servidor y levantar la página, y este si que puede usar worker_threads, cuando tu código se ejecute en el navegador no podrá ejecutar worker_threads.  Lo más cercano a worker_threads en el navegador son los web_workers.
